# filter array to product check in record for events

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an activity feed, it contains a number of different types of activity for our site.

one type of activity is checkin. which logs when a user checks in and checkouts of a site.

The record entries look like so

```
Entryable_id | Entry_type | Action | timestamp

   1             Ticket       Update    12:01
   3             Ticket       New       12:07
   4             CheckIn     ClockedIn  14:30
   4             CheckIn     ClockedOut 17:30
```

What I want to do is create an array with entries in it like so

```
Entryable_id | ClockedIn| ClockedOut
    4            14:30      17:30
```

so far what I have is

```
{

  let staffCheckins = []
  let checkinRecord = []


  if (this.DiaryStore.entries.length) {
    this.DiaryStore.entries.forEach(function(val) {
      if (val.entryable_type === 'CheckIn') {

        staffCheckins.push(val);
        return val
      }
    })
  }

  staffCheckins.forEach(function(val) {

    if (val.action === "ClockedIn") {
      checkinRecord[val.entryable_id] = {
        clockedIn: val.created_at,
        user: val.user
      }
    }


    if (val.action === "ClockedOut") {
      checkinRecord[val.entryable_id] = {
        clockedOut: val.created_at
      }

    }

  })



  console.log(completeCheckin)
},
```

which gives

```
1: clockedIn: "2019-07-22T10:26:45.000000Z",
2: clockedIn: "2019-07-22T12:38:02.000000Z"
```

so I assume that it is not appending to the key when i do

```
checkinRecord[val.entryable_id] =  {clockedOut: val.created_at}
```

On top of that this all feels like a mess. is there a better way to filter and get what I need?

Thanks

Comment: are you just trying to add objects to the checkinRecord array or update them if they already exist?

Comment: When you are populating your staffCheckins array you might want to use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this:
`staffCheckins = this.DiaryStore.entries.filter(val => val.entryable_type === 'CheckIn')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge attribute, instead of assign to new object

```
  staffCheckins.forEach(function(val) {
    if (!checkinRecord[val.entryable_id]) {
      checkinRecord[val.entryable_id] = {}
    }
    if (val.action === "ClockedIn") {
      checkinRecord[val.entryable_id] = {
        ...checkinRecord[val.entryable_id],
        clockedIn: val.created_at,
        user: val.user
      }
    } else (val.action === "ClockedOut") {
      checkinRecord[val.entryable_id] = {
          ...checkinRecord[val.entryable_id],
          clockedOut: val.created_at
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

so I haven't gotten to test it because I'm out and about but you could try something like this. If they object `entryable_id` doesnt exist in the current object in the array, then it will create a new object with the members, otherwise it will find the object and update the fields

```
{
    let staffCheckins = [];
    let checkinRecord = [];

    if (this.DiaryStore.entries.length) {
        staffCheckins = this.DiaryStore.filter(val => val.entryable_type.toLowerCase() === 'checkin');
    }

    staffCheckins.forEach(function(val, i) {
        let { action, entryable_id, created_at, user } = val;

        if (!entryable_id in checkinRecord[i]) {
            checkinRecord[i] = {
                clockedIn: created_at,
                clockedOut: created_at,
                user
            }
        }

        if (action.toLowerCase() === 'clockedin') {
            checkinRecord[i] = {
                ...checkinRecord[i],
                clockedIn: created_at,
                user
            }
        } else if (action.toLowerCase() === 'clockedout') {
            checkinRecord[i] = {
                ...checkinRecord[i],
                clockedOut: created_at
            }
        }
    });
}
```

apologies if I understood wrong but I'm also no currently at my actual computer to test any of it

Answer (score 0):

You could do this whole operation in a filter reduce combination and create a groupBy object using the `Entryable_id` as keys.

Once loop completes get values array of that object

```js
const checkinGroup = data.filter(({Entry_type}) => Entry_type === 'CheckIn')
                .reduce((a, c)=>{
                    let {Entryable_id:id, Action, timestamp} = c;
                    a[id] = a[id] || {Entryable_id: id, ClockedIn: null, ClockedOut: null};
                    a[id][Action] = timestamp;
                    return a;                
                },{});
                
const res = Object.values(checkinGroup)
console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
  const data = [{
      Entryable_id: 1,
      Entry_type: 'Ticket',
      Action: 'Update',
      timestamp: '12:01'
    },
    {
      Entryable_id: 3,
      Entry_type: 'Ticket',
      Action: 'New',
      timestamp: '12:07'
    },
    {
      Entryable_id: 4,
      Entry_type: 'CheckIn',
      Action: 'ClockedIn',
      timestamp: '14:30'
    },
    {
      Entryable_id: 4,
      Entry_type: 'CheckIn',
      Action: 'ClockedOut',
      timestamp: '17:30'
    }
  ]
</script>
```